# draw button as combobox with ios

Tags: iphone, combobox, drawing

I'm attempting to override the `onDraw` method of a button because I want to create a different styled button. I want to create a button like `combobox` with `iOS SDK`. I've already found source code, but it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for combo box in ios.

[IosCombo](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ioscombobox)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many entries you're trying to choose from, you might want to look at [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).  It's like a radial button, where you can select one "active" option (leaving one or more "inactive" options).  It gets cluttered and it becomes hard for the user to select the option they want if you have a lot of different options though.